# Best way to join two relations in SQL?

Tags: sql, database

I have two relations Employees and Tasks. In the relation Employees I save relevant information about the employee including the primary key employee_id. In the relation Tasks I save all relevant information about the tasks including the primary key task_id.

What would be the best way to join these two relations so you know which employee has which task? I assume an employee can have multiple tasks and a task can have multiple employees. Would it be best to add employee_id as a foreign key to tasks like this.

```
CREATE TABLE Employee(
Name TEXT,
Employee_id INT PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE Tasks(
task_description TEXT,
Employee_id INT,
FOREIGN KEY (Employee_id) REFERENCES Employee(Employee_id),
task_id INT PRIMARY KEY
);
```

My problem with this is that since multiple employees can have the same task, it's not a key for the relation Tasks.

Another option I thought about was this. I don't know if this has the desired effect.

```
CREATE TABLE Employee(
Name TEXT,
Employee_id INT PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE Tasks(
task_description TEXT,
Employee_id INT,
task_id INT,
PRIMARY KEY(Employee_id, task_id)
);
```

What other (better) options are there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is, by definition, a [many-to-many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)) relationship that require a separate table:

```
CREATE TABLE EmployeeTasks (
   Employee_id INT,
   Task_id INT,
   PRIMARY KEY (Employee_id, Task_id),
   FOREIGN KEY Employee_Id REFERENCES Employees(Employe_id),
   FOREIGN KEY Task_id REFERENCES Tasks(Task_id));

CREATE INDEX EmployeeTasks_Task_id on EmployeeTasks(Task_id);
```

You should pluralize table names.

Comment: This helped me very much, thank you. I altered all my many-to-many relationships :)